# System.Windows.MessageBox close automatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` as the code below

```
System.Windows.Forms.MyMessageBox result = System.Windows.Forms.MyMessageBox.Show("You have to choose a folder!", "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
{
    //Popup File Dialog
    System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult resultFd = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
    System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
    resultFd = folderDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (resultFd == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Sometimes, The Messagebox will be closed automatically after it showed.

And then, the condition `(result == MessageBoxResult.OK)` sometime equal `TRUE` and sometimes equal  `FALSE`.

Someone can tell me the reason why the MessageBox was closed automatically? and how to fix it?

Many Thanks,

T&T

`UPDATE:` The full code is below

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
        StartingWindow startingWindow = new StartingWindow();            
        startingWindow.RunAndUpdateProgressBar(InitializeAll);
        startingWindow.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void InitializeAll()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
        {
            //Do somethings
            startingWindow.UpdateProgressBar(35);
            //Do somethings
            startingWindow.UpdateProgressBar(65);

            System.Windows.Forms.MyMessageBox result = System.Windows.Forms.MyMessageBox.Show("You have to choose a folder!", "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                //Popup File Dialog
                System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult resultFd = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
                System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
                resultFd = folderDialog.ShowDialog();
                if (resultFd == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //Do something
                }
            }    
            startingWindow.UpdateProgressBar(100); //Set 100%, The startingWindow will be closed by  (***)
        }
    }
}

public partial class StartingWindow : Window
{
    private BackgroundWorker worker;
    public delegate void UpdateProgressBarDelegate();

    public StartingWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BackgroundWorker_DoWork);
        worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged);
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.ApplyTemplate();
    }

    public void RunAndUpdateProgressBar(UpdateProgressBarDelegate runThis)
    {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(runThis);
    }

    public void UpdateProgressBar(int value)
    {
        worker.ReportProgress(value);
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            UpdateProgressBarDelegate updateProgressBarDelegate = e.Argument as UpdateProgressBarDelegate;
            updateProgressBarDelegate();

            double curProgressValue = 0;

            while (curProgressValue < 100)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
                {
                    curProgressValue = progressBar.Value;
                }));
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Global.wrapper.WriteRuntimeLogs(ex.Message + "/n Stack Trace = " + ex.StackTrace);
            MessageBox.Show("An unexpected exception occurs when starting App!");
        }
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(e.ProgressPercentage, duration);
        progressBar.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, animation);    
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = 0;
        Close(); //(***)
    }
}
```

`UPDATE`:

```
namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
    public class MyMessageBox
    {
       public static MessageBoxResult Show
           (
                String messageBoxText,
                String caption,
                MessageBoxButton button,
                MessageBoxImage icon                
            )
        {
            MessageBoxManager.OK = Global.resourceManager.GetString("OK");
            MessageBoxManager.Cancel = Global.resourceManager.GetString("Cancel");
            MessageBoxManager.Abort = Global.resourceManager.GetString("Abort");
            MessageBoxManager.Retry = Global.resourceManager.GetString("Retry");
            MessageBoxManager.Ignore = Global.resourceManager.GetString("Ignore");
            MessageBoxManager.Yes = Global.resourceManager.GetString("Yes");
            MessageBoxManager.No = Global.resourceManager.GetString("No");

            MessageBoxManager.Register();
            MessageBoxResult result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);          
            MessageBoxManager.Unregister();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

`NOTE`: When the `MessageBox` is closed automatically, the `startingWindow` still is showing.

Comment: Hi TTGroup, just a little hint at first: For variable declaration it's better readable to use the keyword `var` instead full classname and namespace. But your code seems to be ok and should work. With this little code snipped it's not possible to reproduce your problem. Do you send some messages through the message queue manually in other parts of your code?

Comment: its weird that your messagebox gets closed automatically..Because i checked it its working fine in my case

Comment: In your case, result is true if you select a folder and confirm, and it is false if you cancel/close the dialog.

Comment: Thanks all, I have updated my post with the full code. Please help me, thanks so much!

Comment: @MarcusWölk, although I tend to agree with you about `var`, it's mostly a matter of preference... Many people prefer to specify the types explicitly.

Comment: @TTGroup: Did you get it work? I tried to reproduce it but i couldn't. For me everything works fine. In WPF I just would prefer to use [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) to make the code easier readable and maintainable. I can post an answer with an MVVM example that's doing the same like your implementation.

Comment: @MarcusWölk: After reading your comment, I checked my code and I see that, I used MyMessageBox instead of MessageBox, maybe this bug is caused by MyMessageBox but I don't sure, I have updated the code, please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @TTGroup: Do you use [this MessageBoxManager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox)?

Comment: @MarcusWölk: Yes I used System.Windows.Forms.MyMessageBox.Show(), sorry I updated code incompletely!

Comment: Ok. I tried it again and your code works fine for me. But maybe this helps: Add a event handler to the `Loaded` event of your `StartingWindow` and call `RunAndUpdateProgressBar(InitializeAll)` in this event handler and NOT in the `MainWindow` constructor. That's better because your code runs in parallel and actually you cannot say what's executed at fist - showing the `MessageBox` or showing the `StartingWindow`?